# Sorting an Excel Pivot Table by a calculated field

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, excel-pivot

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
     A              B              C              D    
1   Product        Category         Sale        Margin
2   Product A       Apparel          500          45%
3   Product A       Apparel          400          30%
4   Product A       Shoes            600          55%
5   Product B       Apparel          300          20%
6   Product C       Beauty           100          40%
7   Product C       Shoes            200          65%
8   Product D       Apparel          450          25%
9   Product D       Beauty           700          50%
10  Product D       Beauty           250          35%
```

Based on this data I create a Pivot Table.
In this Pivot table I added the following **Calculated Field** to get the profit:

```
   Profit = Sale * Margin
```

which leads to the following Pivot Table:

```
            Sum of Profit
Product A     1.950
Product B        60
Product C       315
Product D     1.540
```

Now, I want to **sort** this Pivot Table **descending** so it looks like the following:

```
              Sum of Profit
Product A        1.950
Product D        1.540
Product C          315
Product B           60
```

It seems that for a **Calculated Field** the sorting options in the *PivotTable-Tools* is not available.

Do you have any other idea how I can achieve this sorting?

**NOTE:** I know that I could add the calculation of the profit in **Column E** in the source data. However, my original file is a bit more complex compared to the simplified example above so a **Calculated Field** is unavoidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a cell in the Calculated Field --> Sort --> Sort largest to smallest.

Or you can try the following code to sort the calculated field.

```
Sub SortCalculatedField()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")   'This is the sheet which contains Pivot Table
Set pt = ws.PivotTables(1)
pt.PivotFields("Product").AutoSort xlDescending, "Sum of Profit", pt.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Pivot Tables are unable to sort in usual ways if there is more than one field in the rows section (categorical data). I've tried it in multiple pivot table layouts and it even holds true in the "traditional" pivot table layout. If it's necessary to have more than one categorical element I believe concatenation would be a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this by playing around with PowerPivot. You can convert the data into a data model, then create a Pivot Table.

Next, add a measure (click on the pivot, then a "Power Pivot" tab should appear > Add Measures). You'll need to add a formula (similar to how you created your calculated measure). You should then be able to sort your measure / calculated measure. If you have columns, be sure you do this before you add the columns.